# docker attach - turn tty false to tty true

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am running a docker container and on inspecting it. I find

> "Config": {
>               "Hostname": "amb1.service.consul",
>               "Domainname": "",
>               "User": "",
>               "AttachStdin": false,
>               "AttachStdout": false,
>               "AttachStderr": false,
>               **"Tty": false,**
>               "OpenStdin": false}

Is there any way to attach to this container interactively?

Comment: try `docker exec -it container_id_or_name /bin/bash`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 3):

To be able to interact with the container that is already running. The command is:

```
docker exec -it [name_container] bash
```

Some base image doesnt have bash, in this case run:

```
docker exec -it [name_container] sh
```